# How to plot wordcloud based on multiple columns?

Tags: r, plot, word-cloud

How to make wordcloud plot based on two columns values?
I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina", "Vikram", "Ramesh", "Luther")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26, 41, 32, 58)
Pval <- c(0.01, 0.06, 0.001, 0.002, 0.025, 0.05, 0.01, 0.0002)
df <- data.frame(Name, Age, Pval)
```

I want to make wordcloud plot for `df$Name` based on values in `df$Age` and `df$Pval`. I used following code:

```
library("tm")
library("SnowballC")
library("wordcloud")
library("wordcloud2")
library("RColorBrewer")
set.seed(1234)
wordcloud(words = df$Name, freq = df$Age, min.freq = 1,
          max.words=10, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

[image]

Here `Luther` & `Ben` are of same size, but I need to make `Luther` to be slightly bigger than `Ben` as it has lower Pval.

Comment: Have you weighted the idea of _to_ _color_ the names with `df$Pval` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick fix workaround:

```
library("dplyr")
library("scales")
library("wordcloud")
library("RColorBrewer")

Name <- c("Jon", "Bill", "Maria", "Ben", "Tina", "Vikram", "Ramesh", "Luther")
Age <- c(23, 41, 32, 58, 26, 41, 32, 58)
Pval <- c(0.01, 0.06, 0.001, 0.002, 0.025, 0.05, 0.01, 0.0002)
df <- data.frame(Name, Age, Pval)

df <- df %>%
group_by(Age) %>%
mutate(rank = rank(Pval)) %>% #rank pvalue by age 
mutate(weight = scales::rescale(rank/max(rank), to=c(0,1)))  %>%
#this is just to make sure that we don't add more than one to the mix
mutate(weight = Age + (1-weight) ) #because rank is inversed
#the final thing adds 0.5 if there is not anyone with the same age and 1 if
#there is someone else but you have a smaller p-val (it also should work if 
# there is more than 2 person with the same age)

set.seed(1234)
wordcloud(words = df$Name, freq = df$weight, min.freq = 1,
      max.words=10, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
      colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
```

Fun and interesting question btw